# Is console.dir() in javascript or firefox asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, console, firebug, dir

A very weird problem.

In my debugging, I found that console.dir(anArray) didn't output the current value on browser's firebug console.

For example,

```
console.dir(anArray)              //line 1
console.log(anArray[0].prop1)     //line 2
code to change the value of anArray[0].prop1  //line 3
```

the anArray is an array of javascript/json object,

in Firbug's console, line 1 output the new value, which is set in line 3,

and line 2 is old value, and is what I want.

The only explaning is that console.dir() is asynchronous, right?!

my env:
Windows7, Firefox 6.0.2, firebug 1.9.1, javascript lib is DOJO(but I think have nothing to do with it.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The big thing  with `console.dir`  (at least in Chrome, judging by my experience, and by [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316#c30))  is that the **expansion** evaluates and shows the **current** value of the object, at the moment when you do the expansion, not those at the moment of the `console.dir()` call.

See for example

```
<html><body> open/refresh this with the javascript console open
<script>
 var ar = new Float32Array(1);
 ar[0]=2;   
 console.log(ar[0]);
 console.dir(ar);   
 ar[0]=200; 
</script>
```

When you expand the array in the console, you see the value 200.

It's not supposed to be a bug, and it's surely a performance thing (the object can be very big), but the behaviour is weird, and potentially confusing.

Furthermore, I've tested that if the value changes afterwards, the console does not update it (so it doesn't work as a 'watch' window in a debugger neither).

Answer (score 0):

For short, yes. :)

I had a similar issue with Chrome in the past not understanding my console result, but I ran a few test and discovered then that it was asynchronous behavior. In fact my best bet is that it use internaly a setTimeout() to delay the log. console.log seems to be affected also in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Console log sometimes bugs out like that. It is also less powerful in Internet Explorer (a common place to find bugs), where it can't print things like objects and XML documents.

I suggest that instead of using console.log you instead try to learn how to use the powerful debuggers that the browsers make available. When you are paused on a breakpoint you can inspect all the variables, run arbitrary statements on the console and go up and down the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in both Firefox and Chrome:
run in console:

```
console.log(a = {b: { c: 0}});
a.b.c = 1;
```

the result in Firebug:

```
b: Object { c= 1 }
```

the result in Chrome:

```
b: Object
    c: 1
```